# reverse javascript crackme encryption method algorithm

Tags: obfuscation, javascript

This crackme contains a text input element on the screen and a button to validate

The value you enter is set into **_inputValue**, afterwards you click on a button, the function executes, in the last lines, if **selectedOption** is 2 it will print "Congratz" otherwise there are 5 bad options in the **optionsArr**.

after unpacking and cleaning the main function is :

```
Password: <input/><br/>
<button>Check</button>
<script id="urchin">
    (function () {
        var optionsArr = [
            function () {
                console.warn("boo")
            },
            function () {
                console.warn(":(")
            },
            function () {
                console.log("Congratz!")
            },
            function () {
                console.warn("allmost there")
            },
            function () {
                console.warn("muhaha")
            },
            function () {
                console.warn("nahhh")
            },
            function () {
                console.warn("not even close")
            }
        ];
        var mainFunction = function () {
            var arr = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                arr[i] = i;
            }
            var inputVal = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
            var varX = 0;
//            for (var i2 = 0; i2 < 256; i2++) {
//                var secret = 'click';
//                varX = (varX + arr[i2] + secret.charCodeAt(i2 % 5)) % 256;
//                arr[i2] ^= arr[varX];
//                arr[varX] ^= arr[i2];
//                arr[i2] ^= arr[varX];
//            }
            arr = [99, 116, 115, 37, 16, 120, 211, 90, 197, 22, 166, 63, 146, 59, 123, 237, 93, 44, 76, 118, 168, 91, 55, 187, 62, 220, 135, 49, 127, 185, 153, 8, 66, 155, 152, 181, 117, 149, 31, 87, 169, 6, 172, 34, 101, 134, 107, 157, 199, 231, 124, 2, 243, 35, 241, 139, 68, 3, 159, 86, 77, 225, 105, 29, 144, 19, 32, 42, 227, 147, 133, 15, 160, 73, 190, 148, 82, 97, 170, 201, 212, 14, 18, 13, 193, 121, 143, 141, 182, 122, 21, 108, 112, 111, 217, 60, 250, 27, 137, 244, 191, 38, 171, 214, 248, 132, 228, 43, 232, 213, 223, 129, 28, 64, 247, 205, 138, 95, 202, 235, 61, 119, 224, 88, 238, 206, 230, 94, 195, 5, 179, 54, 72, 92, 136, 98, 188, 200, 173, 226, 198, 4, 71, 196, 126, 9, 69, 110, 84, 48, 85, 210, 30, 180, 229, 216, 162, 56, 75, 0, 67, 253, 163, 167, 53, 26, 7, 12, 174, 57, 130, 194, 209, 165, 1, 140, 183, 70, 23, 89, 150, 25, 145, 104, 233, 74, 142, 151, 222, 65, 207, 96, 154, 218, 106, 131, 255, 109, 254, 33, 113, 164, 203, 40, 246, 83, 192, 236, 189, 78, 158, 234, 177, 175, 161, 251, 100, 221, 219, 103, 50, 41, 242, 10, 249, 240, 20, 184, 24, 80, 52, 51, 81, 11, 156, 245, 114, 239, 186, 125, 17, 204, 128, 47, 36, 39, 215, 208, 46, 176, 178, 58, 45, 102, 252, 79];
            var idx = varX = 0;
            var cmpStr = '';
            for (var i3 = idx; i3 < inputVal.length; i3 += 2) {
                idx = (idx + 1) % 256;
                varX = (varX + arr[idx]) % 256;
                arr[idx] ^= arr[varX];
                arr[varX] ^= arr[idx];
                arr[idx] ^= arr[varX];
                var curHex = inputVal.substr(i3, 2);
                var hex2int = parseInt(curHex, 16);
                var charCode = hex2int ^ arr[(arr[idx] + arr[varX]) % 256];
                cmpStr += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
            }
            var selectedOption = cmpStr.charCodeAt(cmpStr.charCodeAt(0) % cmpStr.length) % 6;

            if (cmpStr != 'input128' && selectedOption == 2) selectedOption++;
            optionsArr[selectedOption]();
        };
        var btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
        if (typeof(btn.addEventListener) != typeof(mainFunction)) {
            btn.attachEvent('onclick', mainFunction);
        } else {
            btn.addEventListener('click', mainFunction, true);
        }
        btn = document.getElementById('urchin');
        btn.parentNode.removeChild(btn);
    })();
</script>
```

I understand my input after decrypt needs to be "input128", how can I reverse the process to encrypt "input128" ?

- BTW, It's using rc4 encryption

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extend on [EWD-0-](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/users/22023/ewd-0) about the reversibility of RC4 here's how I tried it:

From your actual code and reversing it a little to get "input128" encoded:

```
arr = [99, 116, 115, 37, 16, 120, 211, 90, 197, 22, 166, 63, 146, 59, 123, 237, 93, 44, 76, 118, 168, 91, 55, 187, 62, 220, 135, 49, 127, 185, 153, 8, 66, 155, 152, 181, 117, 149, 31, 87, 169, 6, 172, 34, 101, 134, 107, 157, 199, 231, 124, 2, 243, 35, 241, 139, 68, 3, 159, 86, 77, 225, 105, 29, 144, 19, 32, 42, 227, 147, 133, 15, 160, 73, 190, 148, 82, 97, 170, 201, 212, 14, 18, 13, 193, 121, 143, 141, 182, 122, 21, 108, 112, 111, 217, 60, 250, 27, 137, 244, 191, 38, 171, 214, 248, 132, 228, 43, 232, 213, 223, 129, 28, 64, 247, 205, 138, 95, 202, 235, 61, 119, 224, 88, 238, 206, 230, 94, 195, 5, 179, 54, 72, 92, 136, 98, 188, 200, 173, 226, 198, 4, 71, 196, 126, 9, 69, 110, 84, 48, 85, 210, 30, 180, 229, 216, 162, 56, 75, 0, 67, 253, 163, 167, 53, 26, 7, 12, 174, 57, 130, 194, 209, 165, 1, 140, 183, 70, 23, 89, 150, 25, 145, 104, 233, 74, 142, 151, 222, 65, 207, 96, 154, 218, 106, 131, 255, 109, 254, 33, 113, 164, 203, 40, 246, 83, 192, 236, 189, 78, 158, 234, 177, 175, 161, 251, 100, 221, 219, 103, 50, 41, 242, 10, 249, 240, 20, 184, 24, 80, 52, 51, 81, 11, 156, 245, 114, 239, 186, 125, 17, 204, 128, 47, 36, 39, 215, 208, 46, 176, 178, 58, 45, 102, 252, 79];
var idx = varX = 0;
var cmpStr = '';
for (var i3 = idx; i3 < 'input128'.length; i3 += 1) {
  idx = (idx + 1) % 256;
  varX = (varX + arr[idx]) % 256;
  arr[idx] ^= arr[varX];
  arr[varX] ^= arr[idx];
  arr[idx] ^= arr[varX];

  var hex2int = 'input128'.charCodeAt(i3);
  var charCode = hex2int ^ arr[(arr[idx] + arr[varX]) % 256];

  cmpStr += charCode.toString(16)+" ";
}
console.log(cmpStr);
```

Main difference in the loop is running by step of 1 by char, and taking each character code to xor with the corresponding key value. It is then encoded in hex as your original code does read hex values (the loop run by step of 2) to get character code (`curHex` then `hex2int`).

This give me: `95 69 18 b1 82 8 c1 59`

You just have to add a `0` to the 6th entry and remove the spaces to fill `inputValue` and you'll get back 'input128' in `cmpStr`.

Answer (score 1):

RC4 is a Symmetric Key algorithm. So give "input128" as your input. Then debug the code to see what it generates after applying the algorithm on "input128". That would be the original input you have to gave.

**Symmetric Key Algorithms:**

**plaintext + key = ciphertext**

**ciphertext + key = plaintext**

Comment: A little more complex than that imho, at least the input can't be given as is as it need to be entered in hexadecimal form.

Comment: (sounds promising anyway, but I should be failing my reversal program on the numbers part)

Comment: @IddoE check the actual code, it takes input 2 chars by 2 chars as hex value which are then converted to integer and then xored with the corresponding key character code. It's just an extra obfuscation part.